# Bones in the back hurting while doing lie-down exercises

Tags: exercise, injury-prevention

I'm quite the thin tall guy (75kg, 198cm) who recently began to switch up my usual exercise routine. When doing so I discovered that during most exercises done lying down, I have a bit of a problem with my spine and tailbone taking a lot of my bodyweight towards the ground, hurting like hell if I move around. The same goes for my hip when facing the ground, although to a lesser extent.

I'm having a hard time trying to solve the problem as I often enjoy groups training sessions, and those usually include a lot of lying down in my hoods. Is there anything I should be aware of about this problem or anything that can be done to help it a bit?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Any lie-down exercise should be done on a mat.

If your group training session involves lying on your back on the ground without any mats, you should immediately STOP doing that, and seriously question the competence of whoever is arranging these sessions.